# Error while compiling apache sparkSql

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to execute below sparkSQL example,

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQL.java

my pom.xml (i have added sql dependency as well, i am stuck please help)

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Akka repository</id>
      <url>http://repo.akka.io/releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

i have just renamed the file as SimpleApp.java

I get this following error when compiling.. kindly advice

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Project 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ simple-project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Volumes/Official/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2/try/simple-project/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ simple-project ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Volumes/Official/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2/try/simple-project/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Volumes/Official/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2/try/simple-project/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[61,16] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-19T10:30:31+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project simple-project: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Volumes/Official/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2/try/simple-project/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[61,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Seem The program throws error at schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people");

Comment: I have been checking Spark JavaDoc.. cant get any clue.. am i missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue:

In the example

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQL.java

replace the line  `schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people");`

with `schemaPeople.registerAsTable("people");`

compile and package with `mvn compile` and `mvn package` and run with

```
bin/spark-submit --class "org.apache.spark.examples.sql.SimpleApp" --master local[4] try/simple-project/target/simple-project-1.0.jar
```